# Check if first 4 characters in String contain specific words and remove it

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array like this

```
array(
   [0] => 'sku_name'
   [1] => 'price'
   [2] => 'typesku_'
)
```

i want to detect which index that contain 'sku_' at the exact first 4 characters in string and remove the 'sku_'

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: @Jeff right now i only use strpos(), but strpos can detect string like  'typesku_' i only want to remove the first 4 characters in string that contain 'sku_'

Comment: @IdhamChoudry Then check for `stripos(...) === 0` so you check if your value **begins** with 'sku_' (see the return value comment on the according php docs page)

Comment: @Jeff stripos() is working, now i just need to remove it thaanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$yourArray = array(
   'sku_name',
   'price',
   'typesku_'
);

$replaced = array_map(
    function($val)
    {
        if (stripos($val, "sku_") === 0)
        {
            return substr($val, 4);
        }
        return $val;
    },
    $yourArray
);

print_r($replaced);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => name
    [1] => price
    [2] => typesku_
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the answer with stripos

```
$demo=array('sku_name','price','typesku_');
foreach($demo as $k=>$d){
    if(stripos($d, 'sku_')===0){
        $demo[$k]=  str_replace('sku_',"",$d);
    }
}
```

Output
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => price
    [2] => typesku_
)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr=array(0 => 'sku_name', 1 => 'price', 2 => 'typesku_');
$i=0;
$s=0;
foreach($arr as $index){
    if(stripos($index,"sku_")===0){
        $str=strlen($index);
        for ($i=4;$i<$str;$i++){
            $index[$s]=$index[$i];
            $index[$i]="\0";
            $s++;
        }
        echo $index;
        echo "<br>";
    }

}

?>
```

This is one of the ways you can do it, I just thought of it myself, it may not be the best way, but it works, cheers! :) Hope it helps.